# Andengine fo rAndroid

Tags: android, andengine

I am new to use Andengine..

i getting file not found exception error when i am trying with following code.

```
 public void onLoadResources() {
         this.mTexture = new Texture(32, 32, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
         this.mFaceTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/face_box.png", 0, 0);

         this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);
 }
```

Most Probably due to this **gfx/face_box.png**.
How to fix this error? How can I use my own image here. Do I have to give the path of my any gallery image? or I can use any image that resides in the `drawable` folder.

Can any body help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the image you want inside the **assets/gfx/[imagename]** path.

Furthermore make the size of your images so that its dividable by 2:

e.g. 16x16 or 32x32 or 128x32

Comment: Just a side note... you don't have to resize your images, in AndEngine the textures are the ones that must have width and height in power of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, ...)